# Programmatically determine gem's path using bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

I know you can do

```
bundle show gem_name
```

to show the path of some gem.

How do you do that from within the code using the Bundler object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have a look at how they do it in [cli.rb](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb)

```
def locate_gem(name)
  spec = Bundler.load.specs.find{|s| s.name == name }
  raise GemNotFound, "Could not find gem '#{name}' in the current bundle." unless spec
  if spec.name == 'bundler'
    return File.expand_path('../../../', __FILE__)
  end
  spec.full_gem_path
end
```

Comment: This answer, though accepted, is old and there are better answers below.

Answer (score 16):

**Update**: starting with Bundler v1.3.0, there is a *public* interface for obtaining a Gem's path:

```
Bundler.rubygems.find_name('json').first.full_gem_path
# => "/opt/src/foo/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0"
```

Pre-v1.3.0, you may want to use the original solution shared (a *private* interface):

> Better yet, you can use `Bundler::CLI#locate_gem` directly:
>
> ```
> require "bundler/cli"
> Bundler::CLI.new.send(:locate_gem, "json")
> # => "/opt/src/foo/my_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.3"
> ```

Comment: Considering it's not part of the API (being a private method), you will have no guarantee it will change, so may break when Bundler gets updated.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out you actually want to use `Gem` for this, not `Bundler`.

`path = Gem.loaded_specs[NAME_OF_GEM].full_gem_path`

Answer (score 0):

Yup, cli.rb is the best way to look at. However you anyway have to find a spec's name.

I can give you a starting point, but you have to come with some solution on how to optimize to your case:

```
    GemSearcher = Gem::GemPathSearcher.new
    Init = GemSearcher.init_gemspecs()
    GemSearcher.lib_dirs_for(Init[0])
```

Unfortunately this solution provides nameless search as all Gems are in an array instead of hash, but if you want you can hack GemPathSearcher, I think that would be useful in the future.