# How to read files (.yml) from a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, rubygems

I want to read a .yml file included in a Rails Engine Gem from my **main_app**. The file is located at `config/test.yml`.

`IO.read("config/test.yml")` fails with `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

If i move the file into the main app, everything works fine. But i need this file in a Gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can store the root path in a constant from your main gem file and retrieve it in other locations of your code. You must ensure that the gem got initialized before the code in your app runs otherwise you'll have an errors because the constant won't be defined.

```
# lib/my_gem.rb
GEM_ROOT = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)

# app/.../some_class.rb
IO.read("#{GEM_ROOT}/config/test.yml")
```

---

**Solution 2**

The most advisable, you can get the gem path programmatically from `Bundler`, then use that root path to retrieve the full path of your yml file.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322078/programmatically-determine-gems-path-using-bundler) that you can easily adapt to your case

Comment: I'm trying to read the gem's yml file from the main_app, I'm not trying to read the gem's yml file inside the same gem.

Comment: looks like `GEM_ROOT` is also available in the main app. this answer definitely works for both situations. thanks

Comment: I did not get that :) Edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load app yaml files by doing this in your gem:

> YAML.load_file('config/test.yml')